# How to use unix_timestamp( ) function on date comparison on string value

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

How to use unix_timestamp( ) function on date comparison on data type string that in a format of  1/1/2019. The goal is to show all the dates before 1/1/2010. Here is what I'm trying

SELECT 
    work_date
FROM
    table
WHERE
    work_date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-01');

Comment: Do you really want to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` for that purpose? There are probably more efficient options to compare a string stored as date.

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME()`

Comment: like what other options to compare a string as a date ?

Answer (score 0):

> ... date comparison on data type string that in a format of `'1/1/2019'`. The goal is to show all the dates before `'1/1/2010'`.

I don't really see why you would want to specifically use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` for that purpose. Basically you just need to convert your formated string to a date. For that, you can use `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Consider:

```
SELECT work_date 
FROM table 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(work_date, '%e/%c/%Y') <= '2010-01-01';
```

NB: it is impossible to tell if your string date format starts with the month or with the day; the above format stands for the second option, if you want it the other way around then that would be `'%c/%e/%Y'` instead.